# Why #selector() is not working in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn Swift. I want to make side menu in swift. I'd google and found some peace of code. I'm using Xcode 7.2 and swift version 2.1.1?

Error is showing in these following line :-

```
self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ENSideMenu.handleGesture(_:)))// (Expected , separator)
```

HandleGesture method is :-

```
internal func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    toggleMenu((self.menuPosition == .Right && gesture.direction == .Left)
            || (self.menuPosition == .Left && gesture.direction == .Right))
}
```

what should i do?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `#selector()` is in Swift 2.2, no? And you said you version was 2.1.1.

Comment: First reason is given by @Larme and another reason is you have defined your method `internal` which bounds its scope within any source file from their defining module.

Comment: thanks for reply @Larme. I don't know exactly that #selector is work with which version of swift . Currently i'm using 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

try with old syntax

```
self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleGesture:"))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ozgur Ersil. I tried this one. but i'm getting 'Missing argument for parameter action in call'.